# How do I calculate the angle between two points?

Tags: javascript, html, math, geometry

I am attempting to create a 2d tile based game in Javascript, and I need to be able to calculate the angle between two points. I am using the atan2 function to find the angle between two points like so:

```
function getAngleDegrees(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, force360 = true) {
    let deltaX = toX - fromX;
    let deltaY = toY - fromY;
    let radians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
    let degrees = (radians * 180) / Math.PI;
    if (force360) {
      while (degrees >= 360) degrees -= 360;
      while (degrees < 0) degrees += 360;
    }
    return degrees;
  }
```

However, this isn't providing me with the correct result. I have checked the code for logic or math errors and can't find any. No matter what points I input to this function the result will be off by many degrees.

I have created a JS fiddle to visualize the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/fa6o7wdy/40/

If anyone knows how I can fix my angle function to provide the correct result please help!

Edit:

Here is a picture of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpLXC.jpg

Comment: we need a third coordinate, for an angle we need 3 points, one for the center and the other 2 for the points on two lines passing through this center

Comment: Ok what I really want to do is calculate the compass direction (N,E,S,W,NW,NE,SW,SE) from one point to another, is there an easier way to do this that doesn't involve angles? I thought I could calculate the angle from one point to another and convert that into a direction without needing a third point.

Comment: From the jsfiddle I don't see the problem after some runs, the angle seems correctly measured by clockwise start from 0 degree. You need to rewrite your question at least to show what is the correct result you are expecting with some examples or pics.

Comment: please try to be logical: 2 isolated points make no angle, an angle is made up of 2 non-parallel lines, at least 3 points

Comment: I added a picture:

Comment: `Math.atan2` measures angles counterclockwise from the positive X axis when positive Y is up. You have row indexes that go up as they get lower on the page, so you’re getting degrees clockwise from the positive X axis. 68° + 90° = 158°.

Comment: Thank you - that explains it perfectly

Answer (score 5):

Based on the photo sample you provide, for getting the desired angle you want with current `Math.atan()` function, you want to `reverse` first and then `rotate the angle by 90 degrees couter clockwise`

```
function getAngleDegrees(fromX,fromY,toX,toY,force360 = true) {
  let deltaX = fromX-toX; 
  let deltaY = fromY-toY; // reverse
  let radians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)
  let degrees = (radians * 180) / Math.PI - 90; // rotate
  if (force360) {
     while (degrees >= 360) degrees -= 360;
     while (degrees < 0) degrees += 360;
  }
  console.log('angle to degree:',{deltaX,deltaY,radians,degrees})
  return degrees;
}
```

or simply + 90 degrees to this line without changing `deltaX` and `deltaY`

`let degrees = (radians * 180) / Math.PI + 90; // rotate`

Note: I haven't test out all possible edge cases

```js
const inBlk = document.createElement('i')
  ,   getXY = (p,xy) => Number(p.split('-')[xy==='x'?0:1])
  ;   
for(let i=0;i<100;i++)  // build Grid
  {
  let nI = inBlk.cloneNode()
    , u1 = i%10
    ;
  nI.textContent = u1+'-'+(i-u1)/10
  grid.appendChild(nI)
  }
let points = [ {x:0, y:0, old:null}, {x:0, y:0, old:null}]
  , pN     = 0
  ;
grid.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('i')) return

  let elm = e.target.textContent
  points[pN].x = getXY(elm, 'x')
  points[pN].y = getXY(elm, 'y')

  if (points[pN].old ) points[pN].old.classList.remove('color_0', 'color_1')

  points[pN].old = e.target
  points[pN].old.classList.add(`color_${pN}` )

  pN = ++pN %2
  if (pN==0) angle.textContent = ` angle: ${getAngleDegrees(points[0],points[1])}°`
  }

function getAngleDegrees( from, to, force360 =true)
  {
  let deltaX  = from.x - to.x 
    , deltaY  = from.y - to.y                  // reverse
    , radians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)
    , degrees = (radians * 180) / Math.PI - 90  // rotate
    ;
  if (force360)
    {
    while (degrees >= 360) degrees -= 360;
    while (degrees < 0)    degrees += 360;
    }
  return degrees.toFixed(2)
  }
```

```css
:root { --sz-hw: 26px; }
#grid { 
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size  : 10px;
  margin     : calc( var(--sz-hw) /2);
  }    
#grid i {
  display    : block;
  float      : left;
  width      : var(--sz-hw);
  height     : var(--sz-hw);
  border     : 1px solid grey;
  text-align : center;
  margin     : 2px;
  line-height: var(--sz-hw);
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
#grid i:nth-child(10n-9) {clear: both;   }
.color_0 { background-color: lightcoral; }
.color_1 { background-color: lightgreen; }
#angle   { padding: calc( var(--sz-hw) /2) 0 0 calc( var(--sz-hw) *13.4); }
```

```html
<p id="grid"></p>

<h4 id="angle">angle: ?</h4>
```

Comment: I added a snippet in your answer, hope you like it?

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the answer... this one was driving me crazy. Upvoted of course.

Answer (score 3):

DeltaX toX and fromX needed to be swapped around, same goes for DeltaY. Also, I've subtracted 90 to angle, in order to make 0 degree being North.

The % (mod) operator does same job as your 2 x while loop.

```
function getAngleDegrees(fromX,fromY,toX,toY,force360 = true) {
    let deltaX = fromX - toX;
    let deltaY = fromY - toY;
    let radians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)
    let degrees = ((radians * 180) / Math.PI) - 90;
    if (force360) {
       degrees  = (degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    console.log('angle to degree:',{deltaX,deltaY,radians,degrees})
    return degrees;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the code correction... that's definitely better than having 2 while loops, I agree =)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly, it's just that you have a bit of confusion in your coordinate system.

The angle between 2 points is relative to where you measure from. By subtracting P2 from P1, you're making the angle relative to your starting point. Thus, `atan2` is giving you the clockwise angle relative to the X axis.

Traditionally, the X axis is the starting point for rotations, so a horizontal line has an angle of 0:

```
x = 1;
y = 0;
angle = atan2(y, x) // Equals 0
```

You've got your grid with `Y+` going down, so as Y becomes positive, you'll get clockwise angles from the x-axis.

```
x = 0;
y = 1;
angle = atan2(y, x) // Equals PI/2, or 90deg
```

If this is confusing with Y+ going down, you may want to rethink your grid so that Y+ goes up instead.

PS: Good luck on your game!

Comment: Thank you... my lack of higher maths classes is showing. I don't think I could've figured this out on my own.

Comment: Eh, you'll get used to it eventually. Just takes a bit of time.